"System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows" when dynamically loading assembly on a Windows machine
A console application dynamically loads an assembly containing a class that refers System.IO.Ports.
Both the application and the class library target net8.0-windows.
I get the exception System.IO.Ports is currently only supported on Windows., even though the command OperatingSystem.IsWindows() returns true.
If I add a reference to the class library from console application the error disappears.
I guess that during dynamic loading the information about the target runtime is lost.
Adding
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers> 

to projects does not help.
A minimal reproducible example is available on GitHub.
Console application project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>

Class library project file:

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="8.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Program.cs:
using System.Reflection;

try
{
    var serialPortPath = "..\\..\\..\\..\\SerialPort\\bin\\Debug\\net8.0-windows\\SerialPort.dll";
    var serialAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(serialPortPath);
    var serialPort = Activator.CreateInstance(serialAssembly.GetType("SerialPort.SerialPort"));
}
catch    
{
    // Do nothing
}

SerialPort.cs:
namespace SerialPort
{
    public class SerialPort
    {
        public SerialPort()
        {
            var serial = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
        }
    }
}

The exception throws at
var serial = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();

EDIT: I'm aware of LoadContext, but I don't understand the root of the problem yet: if I directly refer the assembly it correctly finds the Windows dll, why the information about target platform is lost when loading via Assembly.LoadFrom?

What happens if you add the NuGet package to the console app too?

@MatthewWatson if I add the NuGet then the exception does not throw

Maybe these articles will be helpful? Loading System.IO.Ports.dll from dynamically loaded class library in .NET6, Create a .NET Core application with plugins, samples/core/extensions/AppWithPlugin/

Because SerialPort.dll depends on System.IO.Ports.dll, when you load SerialPort.dll, the runtime automatically loads System.IO.Ports.dll from the same folder, but unfortunately this is a wrong assembly file, the right assembly file to load is located in runtimes\win\lib\net8.0\ folder. To resolve the dependency path, you need to create a custom AssemblyLoadContext and an AssemblyDependencyResolver, also ensure that SerialPort.deps.json is generated along with SerialPort.dll:
var customALC = new CustomALC();
....
var serialAssembly = customALC.Load(serialPortPath);
....

class CustomALC : AssemblyLoadContext
{
    private AssemblyDependencyResolver? _resolver;

    protected override Assembly? Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
    {
        var path = _resolver?.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
        return path != null ? LoadFromAssemblyPath(path) : null;
    }

    public Assembly Load(string path)
    {
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
        _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(path);
        return LoadFromAssemblyPath(path);
    }
}


thanks for your meaningful explanation. Unfortunately, it does not fix completely my problem, dynamic loading is due to not knowing in advance what I will need later, and inserting the proposed LoadFrom seems like directly adding a reference to System.IO.Ports

I have updated the answer, and this method can automatically load the required dependencies.

I'm aware of Load Contexts, but they introduce additional issues, for example logging libraries (in my case Serilog) are loaded several times, I need to introduce exceptions in load rules, and they get more and more complicated, for example to correctly manage MudBlazor assemblies.
Nevertheless, I still don't understand the root cause of this issue: if I directly refer the assembly it correctly finds the Windows dll, why this information about target platform is lost when loading via Assembly.LoadFrom?

If you directly refer the assembly, it and its dependencies will be copied to the output directory of the host project, a .deps.json will also be generated in the directory, so that the runtime is able to find them.
